# Does assignTo call setter?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a `VisualForce Component` that basically looks like:

```
<apex:component controller="MyController">
    <apex:attribute name="recordId" assignto="{!controllingId}" type="Id" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!controllingRecord.Name}" />
</apex:component>
```

The controller looks like:

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public SObject controllingRecord
    {
        get
        {
            system.debug(controllingRecord); // null
            return controllingRecord;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public Id controllingId
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            controllingId = value;
            String soql = String.format('SELECT Name FROM {0} WHERE Id = {1}',
                new List<String> {
                    String.valueOf(controllingId.getSObjectType()),
                    '\'' + controllingId + '\''
            });
            controllingRecord = Database.query(soql);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not seeing any content. Why would the `setter` not get called?

Comment: If you change your controller's implementation to a vanilla `{ get; set; }` on the `controllingId` member and then change the `controllingRecord` implementation instead to a method `getControllingRecord()` with the dynamic SOQL statement in it - does the behavior change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use the expression syntax for it to work:

```
<apex:component controller="MyController">
    <apex:attribute name="recordId" assignto="{!controllingId}" type="Id" />
</apex:component>
```

---

## POC

### Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <c:component102443 controllerId="{!Account.Id}" />
</apex:page>
```

### Component

```
<apex:component controller="controller102443">
    <apex:attribute name="controllerId" assignTo="{!recordId}" type="Id" description="" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!record['Name']}" />
</apex:component>
```

### Controller

```
public class controller102443 {
    public SObject record {
        public get {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record.Id);
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record.get('Name'));
            return record;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public Id recordId {
        get;
        set {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, value);
            recordId = value;
            record = Database.query('SELECT Name FROM '+String.valueOf(recordId.getSobjectType())+' WHERE Id = :recordId');
        }
    }

    public Id getRecordIdEcho() {
        return recordId;
    }
}
```

---

If this code didn't work, then `{!recordIdEcho}` would be blank. Also, you can verify the debug logs.

---

## Edit

`{!record.Name}` isn't valid for a generic sobject, so you may need to use `{!record['Name']}` to get this code to compile; if you're using a concrete object, you can then access Name directly. Regardless, this POC definitely demonstrates that everything is working as intended, because otherwise we'd get some nice NullPointerException errors in our Visualforce page.

Comment: Ah yes I am doing that already, just a typo. It still does not seem to be calling it. I'll keep digging at why, maybe it's an order of operations thing.

Comment: I'll draft up a demo for you...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Take a look the example code, play with it, try it out.

Comment: Can you please look at my updated example with a better description of what I'm struggling with?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Take another look, then. Except for a minor syntactical change, my code is now basically identical to your own, and yet it works. There might be something *else* that's wrong with your code, but not the particular structure you're using.

Comment: Apparently if the `getter` is missing or `private`, that breaks it for me. I'm not sure if I should update this question, post a new one, or just let it lie.